# uploading app into AppStore

Tags: iphone, deployment, appstore-approval

I want to confirm something about uploading app into the AppStore. Since this is my first attempt, I have my doubts. But let me cut short the question. Will the app that I send to iTunes Connect be automatically uploaded into AppStore, or I have to do it myself? When I wish to update the application, do I need to send back to iTunes Connect to review it too? I have some more questions, but it is after these questions.

So sorry about this. I am a noob when it comes to uploading to AppStore. I seriously think that this question is gonna pile up for me....

**EDIT:**

If I re-upload the corrected binary DURING a review, what will happen? Will it undergo review again?
Or if I upload a newer version of the app, do I need to go through a review again?

Comment: They answer all of this on the itunes connect portal...

Comment: Alright, I go read it up again. I think I might have been too anxious about this and forgotten it.

Comment: HI Melvin.If you feel any Problem give me your Skype id i will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, submitting your app in iTunesConnect will mean it will go live in the app store on the date you set it to go live (assuming it gets approved by Apple). When you update, there is a link in iTunesConnect to upload a new version of your app.

Comment: I see, that is so cool. And I just edited my question, I would like to see the binary I have uploaded into AppStore. I do not recall where I placed the binary I created. :(